# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{n}{2^n} $ diverge or converge?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot  \frac{n}{2^n}$ converges.

I was trying the ratio test:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ converges if $ q:=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$ and diverges if $q >1$.

So we get: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot \frac{2^n}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n2^n+2^n}{n2^{n+1}}$.

How do you calculate the limit of this function? I'm currently practicing for an exam and the solution just used this step:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}} = \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{2} < 1$ therefore convergent. However I really don't see how you transform $\frac{\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}}{\frac{n}{2^n}}$ to $\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: $\frac{n2^n + 2^n}{n2^{n+1}} = \frac{n2^n(1+\frac{1}{n})}{n2^n \cdot 2} = \frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{2}$

Comment: @DominikKutek You're a life saviour, second time you helped me today. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Alternating series with terms that tend to 0. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the ratio test, reorganize the fraction into two fractions made of similar pieces. So when you have $\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{2^n}{n}$, move things around to get $\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}$. Since similar expressions are now together, it makes simplifying easier. In this case you can rewrite it as $(1+\frac{1}{n})\cdot\frac12$. (If the first factor had more in the denominator than just $n$, so you could split it into 2 fractions, you could use l'Hospital's rule, or there are general rules for finding limits of rational functions.)

This kind of regrouping is also crucial when your series has factorials in it.

Answer (score 2):

When $|x|<1$ the geometric series $$(1+x)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-x)^k$$ converges
. Differentiating it w.r.t $x$, we get
$$-(1+x)^{-2}=-(-x)^{-1}\sum_{k=0} k(-x)^k \implies S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^k=-x(1+x)^{-2}$$
Let $x=1/2$, then $$S=-2/9<\infty.$$
So the series converges.

Comment: The answer might be misleading here. The way it is written it seems like the convergence follows from the fact that the simplification of the sum gives a finite number. But for example if $S = \sum x^k = 1/(1-x) =: f(x)$, $S$ only converges for $|x|<1$ although $f(-2) = 1/3 < \infty$

Comment: Small typo: after the implication arrow, you forgot to write the $k$ in the series.

Comment: @LL 3.14 The sum is finite under $|x|<1$, whereas $ |-3|>1.$

Comment: Yes, exactly, but you are not proving it for the derivative. In general convergence of sum does not imply convergence of the derivative. You need an argument for that, such as a theorem about analytic series or the absolute convergence of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternating series, i.e., the terms alternate between positive and negative.

Also, the general term abslute value $|a_n| = \frac{n}{2^n} \to 0$ monotonically, as $n\to \infty$.

Then, by the [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), we have that the series converge.

Comment: That's right. I am going to edit now to add this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_n=\frac n{2^n}$, then we have that $a_n\geq 0$ and
$$a_n-a_{n+1}=\frac{n-1}{2^{n+1}}\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$\implies a_n\geq a_{n+1}\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N}$$
also $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Hence by ***Alternating series test***
,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^na_n\text{ connverges}$$